# Is it possible to access Dropbox accounts details with one app_key & app_secret like Facebook?

Tags: php, dropbox

I am currently working on a PHP project, in which I want to give facility  to user that they can store their data in Dropbox if user is not log in with Dropbox then user have to login first, then on user login I want to list all the contents of their folder stored in Dropbox server. For listing contents I need API key and app_secret of user account app, but this is not feasible to force user to create these key.

Is there any way, I can access details of my user dropbox account contents, like Facebook we have to create one API key and we can access any user details with one API key.

Comment: `"access any user details with one api key"` - this is not 100% correct since you still need all users to have logged into and authenticate your application. There *has* to be some form of user interaction with your application where they can authorise your app.

Comment: yes all user will login with my application, then this whole process will start.

Comment: Can you please suggest me any solution or any other site for this problem?

Comment: Sorry - I am not familiar with the dropbox API

Answer (score 0):

In the Dropbox API, you as the developer of the API app just need to register your app with Dropbox once. Once you do, you get an app key and secret for your app. This identifies your app, and does not allow access to any user accounts.

You should use that app key and secret in your app. Your users don't need to register their own apps.

Users using your app will go through the app authorization flow using your app (which uses your app's app key and secret). Once they authorize the app, the app receives an access token. That access token identifies that user-app pair, and allows access to that user's account.

Answer (score 0):

let me try to explain my requirements once again, In my applicaton,I have 3 types of user role, super admin,admin,normal user. every admin will have a dropbox account, whenever admin will login in to  my app, I will give a link to admin dashboard "link file", on click a window will open for dropbox, if admin user is not loged in then user needs to login first with dropbox, after login, I want to list all his files and user can upload more file as well, for listing user account contents I need api key, screat key(I have implemented this in my own account for listing contents), but I don't want to force my user to create api key and screat key for their account.

I want, only super admin will create api key, screat key and these keys will hardcoded for admin user, On admin login,I just want to list admin dropbox contents and give upload facility.